# How to use tramp with an SSH config file?

Tags: tramp, ssh

I have an ssh config file generated by vagrant ssh that looks like this

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /<my-working-directory>/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

I have seen [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901030/tramp-mode-in-emacs-using-ssh-config) that you can use `C-x C-f /sshx:<ssh config host name>` to connect. Mine looks like its named default. However, how do I specify the location of this config file so that tramp can find this "default" ssh config? Im assuming it at least needs to know my Identity file

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this was due to me not understanding how ssh works. This is the config of the vagrant machine yes. But its for me to put in my own ~/.ssh/config file so that I can ssh into whatever I name it.

so in my ~/.ssh/config I appended it to the existing entries

```
Host some-other-host
  HostName 43.203.234.33
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host vagrant
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /<my-working-dir>/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

and now I can ssh vagrant for instance. OR for tramp: `C-x C-f /sshx:vagrant:/home/vagrant/some-file`